# OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7:

Tags: django, geodjango

Anytime I include `django.contrib.gis' to my INSTALLED_APPS I get this error on my console:

```
OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7: undefined symbol: sqlite3_create_function_v2
```

Comment: outdated sqlite .so?

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do i update it?

Comment: I would start with apt-get.